# Select all children of a ParentID given only a childID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in a SQL Server db that contains two identifying columns: a parent and a child. For instance:

```
ParentID    ChildID
1           101
1           102
1           103
2           104
2           105
2           106
```

I want to select all children of a parent, given only the ChildID. So given 101, I would get 101,102,and 103 since they all share the same parent. I know this can be done by a self join or using CROSS APPLY, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE1 T
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT ChildID
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE ParentID= T.ParentID
) CA
WHERE T.ChildID= @ChildID
```

Is there a grouping function that would be better suited to this, or should I just keep the self join?

**EDIT:** Also trying to avoid using a CTE

Comment: So you want all siblings?

Comment: Yes. I should also add that I'm looking for a non-CTE solution as well. Not because I hate CTEs though

Comment: Curious why you are avoiding CTE now...

Comment: Just wondering what non-CTE and self joining solutions are available. Maybe a ROLLUP or CUBE but I'm not as familiar with those groupings

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do it. It's very hard to tell which of them is best performance wise. Easiest thing to do is run your favorite ways in SSMS all in the same query window, and include the actual execution plan.

One more option that I think is very readable is this:

```
SELECT ParentID, ChildID
FROM TABLE1 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ParentID
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE ChildID = @YourChildId
) T ON TABLE1.ParentID = T.ParentID
```

Comment: I tested this and it actually does have the same execution plan has my CROSS APPLY version. I agree this is a bit more readable

Answer (score 0):

Another option...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    ParentID INT NOT NULL,
    ChildID INT NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #TestData(ParentID, ChildID) VALUES 
    (1, 101), (1, 102), (1, 103), (2, 104), (2, 105), (2, 106);

--============================================

SELECT 
    td1.ParentID,
    td1.ChildID
FROM 
    #TestData td1
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM 
                #TestData td2 
            WHERE 
                td1.ParentID = td2.ParentID 
                AND td2.ChildID = 101
            );
```